# No suitable constructor was found. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Why can't Entity Framework handle binding these constructor parameters to their properties?

Code:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class NObject : Node
{
    public NObjectType Type { get; set; } // Need constructor so this isn't null.
    public List<NObjectTYpeProperty> Properties { get; set; } = new();

    public NObject(NObjectType type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

Error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'NObject'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
>
> Cannot bind 'type' in 'NObject(NObjectType type)'
>
> Note that only mapped properties can be bound to constructor parameters. Navigation to related entities, including references to owned types, cannot be bound.

Searching online, I see there are two solutions to making sure the binding works. One is to have a parameterless constructor, however I need `NObject.Type` to not be null, so a constructor is needed. The second is to ensure the parameters are identical to the property names (but camelCase), however I have done this.

Why can't it figure out the names match up? Are there any `[Attributes]` I can use to link them up manually, or am I just out of luck here?

Comment: Is `NObjectType` another entity? Because EFCore [cannot set a navigation property using constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)

Comment: So the issue isn't that it can't match up the member names but that it doesn't work with other entities? So if the field was an int or something, it would then work?

Comment: Yes, Entities can only be bound through property setters. Constructor binding only works for what traditionally are columns in a table.